# Bootstrap modal not launching

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am a beginner in Bootstrap and learning from this [site](http://bootstrapdocs.com/v1.3.0/docs/javascript.html#overview)
This is my code and when i press `launch modal` nothing happens
Please tell me what I have missed

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Prices for todo app</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="bootstrap-3.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link href="bootstrap-3.0.0/dist/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="bootstrap-3.0.0/assets/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="bootstrap-3.0.0/assets/js/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<a class="btn" data-controls-modal="my-modal" data-backdrop="true" >Launch Modal</a>
<form role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputFile">File input</label>
    <input type="file" id="exampleInputFile">
    <p class="help-block">Example block-level help text here.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox"> Check me out
    </label>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="bootstrap-3.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
    var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
    po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
  })();
  $('#my-modal').modal({
  show:true,
  closeOnEscape: true
});
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you check console? No errors?

Comment: @DonovanCharpin no errors in console.I am using google chrome and in the console no error is showing

Comment: Where is your `#my-modal` element?

Comment: @OswaldoAcauan **#my-modal element** means what?

Comment: But where is the HTML of you modal? http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Comment: Bootstrap Modal is HTML dependent, you need to create the `#my-modal` element before. Look at the docs http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Comment: @Skelly IS bootstrap different from twitter-bootstrap?

Comment: Yes, the `bootstrap` tag is: "A series of procedures run when an application starts up or a request over the web is received." (not twitter bootstrap)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling a modal that doesn't exist (you need to place the html for the modal in the page), and second it is not tied to the launch link in any way (it will pop up on its own). Add your modal html and then edit:

```
$('#my-modal').modal({
  show:true,
  closeOnEscape: true
});
```

to

```
$('a.btn').click(function () {
  $('#my-modal').modal({
      show: true,
      closeOnEscape: true
  });
});
```

Also, Oswaldo is correct that you don't have to have the custom javascript to call your modal at all. If you ARE going to specify specific attributes and load it through your own code though, you do need to put it in a click event or it will pop-up automatically (if you have it as you wrote, with show: true). If you use the custom code to pop up you don't need to add the data bits at all, and vice-versa.

So updated, with custom js: 
http://jsfiddle.net/spacebean/WgQt3/10/

With no additional js:
http://jsfiddle.net/spacebean/WgQt3/9/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/WgQt3/3/ Look at this, without any javascript. The problem on your question is about forgot the modal html markup.

Comment: @spacebean In your answer you have written **<div class="form-group">** can you tell me in which css file its defined.Suppose it is there in bootstrap.css then there will be also other class definition ,so how to know each and every class uses

Comment: Sorry, that was taken from the new bootstrap example code. I do recommend upgrading, there is a lot more available: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals I will update my code to reflect the correct version of bootstrap you are using.

Answer (score 4):

I really recommend you to dont use Twitter Bootstrap v1.3.0, go for v2.3.2 or v3.0.0.

Anyway, Bootstrap Modal is HTML dependent, you need the `#my-modal` element in your HTML with the following markup.

TB v.1.3.0:

```
<a class="btn" data-controls-modal="my-modal" data-backdrop="true" >Launch Modal</a>
<div id="my-modal" class="modal hide fade" style="display: none;">
    <div class="modal-header"> <a href="#" class="close">×</a>
         <h3>Modal Heading</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body…</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer"> <a href="#" class="btn primary">Primary</a>
 <a href="#" class="btn secondary">Secondary</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

TB v.2.3.2:

```
<a href="#my-modal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Launch demo modal</a>
<div id="my-modal" class="modal hide fade">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h3>Modal header</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>One fine body…</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="#" class="btn">Close</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

TB v3.0.0:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="#my-modal" class="btn btn-primary">Launch demo modal</a>
<div class="modal fade" id="my-modal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Comment: I am really new to Twitter-bootstrap just started to learn few hours back.Well may this will be off the topic but please tell me for a beginner from where do I need to start for bootstrap.Please share some links for a beginner.thanks again for helping so +1

Comment: Start reading the docs. http://getbootstrap.com/

You are using a v3.0.0 and following the v1.3.0 docs.

Comment: the link you have shared is the official site,do you mean from where I can get some examples.For example in java2s.com I will find source codes for java apps

Comment: The official site have examples for every single component.

Comment: one last question in this code **<div class="modal fade" id="my-modal">** where is modal fade defined,I know this will be in bootstrap.css but my question is which other class are present and their uses how to know?

Comment: if you dont want fade effect, just remove `fade` class.

Comment: I am just wondering where the classes like **fade** or **modal** are defined.My question is suppose I want fadding then i use fade class so where it(fade) is exactly defined

Answer (score 2):

You have forget to put your html [**modal**](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) which is not displayed.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          ...
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
  </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

and after your jQuery that you can run with click event for example

```
$('#my-modal').modal();
```

Comment: I tried with your code but its not working.Can you give the full working example?

Comment: Is this **<a class="btn" data-controls-modal="my-modal" data-backdrop="true" >Launch Modal</a>** is of no use

Comment: I was modifying my jsFiddle, but spacebean is faster :).

Answer (score 1):

Add this at the last, before closing the body tag...

Optional JavaScript --> jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use that syntex of jquery

```
$(function(){

$("#buttonId").click(
function(){
$("#modelId").modal('show');
});

});
```

This works on my case.Thanks